# Sqlite CTE-insert within trigger gives a syntax error

Tags: sqlite, triggers, insert, common-table-expression

I'm having problems with my code and I just can't seem to figure out what the problem is, so I thought I'd put it in here in hopes that others might spot the error (or confirm my growing suspicion of a bug).

So basically the code is equivalent to this, and all I get even with this sample code is "Error: near "INSERT": syntax error" even though the CTE-insert should be completely legal and it works when not within a trigger. I'm using Sqlite 3.8.7.

```
CREATE TABLE a (val INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE b (val INTEGER);

CREATE TRIGGER update_b AFTER INSERT ON a
BEGIN 
    WITH prev AS (
        SELECT
            0 AS val
        )
        INSERT INTO b(
            val
        )
        SELECT
            prev.val
        FROM prev;
END;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) says:

> The WITH clause cannot be used within a CREATE TRIGGER.

Comment: Oh! Well that explains it then. Kinda odd limitation and the whole error message wasn't really very helpful, but at least now I know what the problem is. Thanks!